# Cant compile, class not declared Java

Tags: java, jgrasp

I'm trying to do this following program. I deleted the last part of `MyRectangle2D` in order to shorten it down a bit.
When I try to compile I get 2 errors, i just can't work my way through!

```
TestExample.java:17: class GeometricObject2 is public, should be declared in a file named GeometricObject2.java
public abstract class GeometricObject2 {

TestExample.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor MyRectangle2D(double,double,double,double)
location: class MyRectangle2D
      GeometricObject2 rectangle1 = new MyRectangle2D(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);

2 errors
```

help is much appreciated !

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestExample
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      GeometricObject2 rectangle1 = new MyRectangle2D(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
      System.out.println(rectangle1.getArea());
   }
}


public abstract class GeometricObject2 {
  private String color = "white";
  private boolean filled;


  protected GeometricObject2() {
  }


  protected GeometricObject2(String color, boolean filled) {
    this.color = color;
    this.filled = filled;
  }

  public String getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  public boolean isFilled() {
    return filled;
  }

  public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
    this.filled = filled;
  }

  public abstract double getArea();

  public abstract double getPerimeter();
}



class MyRectangle2D extends GeometricObject2 {
```

}

Comment: You haven't even read the error message ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement everything in `TestExample.java` file, then I would try something like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GeometricObject2 rectangle1 = new MyRectangle2D(2, 2, 3, 4, "Red", true);
        System.out.println(rectangle1.getArea());
    }
}


abstract class GeometricObject2 {
    private String color = "white";
    private boolean filled;


    protected GeometricObject2() {
    }


    protected GeometricObject2(String color, boolean filled) {
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public abstract double getArea();

    public abstract double getPerimeter();
}



class MyRectangle2D extends GeometricObject2
{
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public MyRectangle2D(double x, double y, double width, double height,
                         String color, boolean filled) {
        super(color, filled);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (width + height);
    }
}
```

And you didn't post the full code of `MyRectangle2D` class, so I really don't know how you intend to implement it...

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! The compiler does however still give me the error, even though i changed the variables. :( any idea why?

Comment: The code above compiles for me. What are the error messages and what did you change?

Comment: I just changed the variables ! to the exact same as you. 

TestExample.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor MyRectangle2D(java.lang.String,boolean)
location: class MyRectangle2D
      GeometricObject2 rectangle1 = new MyRectangle2D("Red", true);
                             
1 error

Comment: Did you implement everything like I did in `TestExample` class? Note that I have also implemented the `MyRectangle2D`class in `TestExample` class. (scroll further down)

Comment: I've implemented my own `MyRectangle2D` class with dummy implementations, because you didn't post the full code. (Btw. if you find this answer useful, it would be great, if you could accept or upvote the answer, which would get me some stackoverflow credit points)

Comment: it works when i do the exact same as you in my MyRectangle2D class.. However i would like to implement 4 more variables in my Rectangle constructor. Namely x, y, width & height! :)

Comment: I have updated the code! But I am not sure, what the x,y values are for. Are they coordinates of a corner vertex?

Comment: It is supposed represent the center of the rectangle. :)

Answer (score 1):

Java requires that a public class called Foo be defined in a source file called Foo.java - this means that you can't declare two public classes in the same .java file (since the file has only one name)

You'll need to move the definition of GeometricObject2 to its own file, which will be called GeometricObject2.java. That should get you through to your next error. :)

EDIT: as other posters have noted, you could also make the abstract class non-public, but this seems less than useful to me.

Comment: Thank you very much! this made the difference.. Im still weirded out about it! why does it even make sense? i thought that the compiler by default made the classes?

Comment: Briefly, it has to do with the way that the classloader finds a class. If you refer to a class, it's going to check on your classpath to see if it exists already. If it doesn't, it's going to look for a file with the right name, and try to compile that.

Comment: "i thought that the compiler by default made the classes?" The compiler only compiles what it needs - if you make public classes Foo, Bar, and Baz, each in their own file, and Foo refers to Bar but neither refers to Baz, then when you compile Foo, you'll find that Bar is compiled to Bar.class, but Baz is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep multiple classes within one file, you need to remove the public keyword. So should be `abstract class GeometricObject2` without the public in front.

Your second error mentions a missing constructor, but for this you would need to provide the code for MyRectangle2D class

UPDATE

so now, with the class in the comment, your constructor issue is due to the missing constructor that accepts only four doubles. What would fix your compile based on the code you've added woulb be changing to

`GeometricObject2 rectangle1 = new MyRectangle2D(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, "Red", true);`

Comment: This is a strip of the code for MyRectangle2D :) 


class MyRectangle2D extends GeometricObject2 {
   private double x = 0;
   private double y = 0;
   private double width = 0;
   private double height = 0;
   
   MyRectangle2D() {
   }
   
   MyRectangle2D(double x, double y, double width, double height, String color, boolean filled) {
      super(color, filled);
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;